# GRUB booting to command line after system restart

Tags: 16.04, dual-boot, grub2, kubuntu

After turning on my computer initially, I get the regular GRUB menu (as desired) with the different boot options:

[image: Regular GRUB menu with boot options]

But after restarting my computer, I am instead greeted with the GRUB terminal, which I don't want:

[image: GRUB command line]

The only way to bring back the GRUB menu is to shutdown from the GRUB command line using `halt`, press the laptop's physical reset button, wait for a few minutes, and finally turn the computer back on.

**Obviously, using the reset button or manually loading the OS is time-consuming and inconvenient. I'd like to have the GRUB menu show up consistently but don't know how to enforce that.**

I am running a dual-boot system with Kubuntu 16.04.3 LTS and Windows 10, with the drives partitioned [like this](https://pastebin.com/q33fMSqp). Both OSes are set to UEFI and secure boot is disabled.

Some solutions I have attempted, to no avail:

- Reinstalling GRUB from Ubuntu using `grub-install`, then running `update-grub`. This seems to be the most common solution but changes nothing for me.
- Running the "Recommended repair" option from the `boot-repair` utility. This added a few menu entries to the GRUB menu but didn't stop the command line from showing up.
- Purging and reinstalling `grub-efi`
- Pressing <kbd>c</kbd> or holding <kbd>Shift</kbd> before GRUB loads
- Removing from `/etc/fstab` all entries involving an NTFS filesystem
- Adding `libata.force=noncq` to the line `GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_DEFAULT` from `/etc/default/grub` (GRUB and the root partition are stored on an SSD)

Comment: What brand/model computer? May be best to see details, you can run from your Ubuntu live installer or any working install, use ppa version not older Boot-Repair ISO:
Post the link to the Create BootInfo summary report. Is part of Boot-Repair:
https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Boot-Info and:
https://sourceforge.net/p/boot-repair/home/Home/

Comment: Hi oldfred, my computer model is an [MSI GS60 2PC Ghost](https://www.msi.com/Laptop/GS60-2PC-Ghost.html#hero-overview). Here is the [BootInfo summary](https://pastebin.com/BZpxnVa2).

Comment: It appears that you have ubuntu installed on drive sdb, this is where grubs config file is kept. A grub commandline means that grub launched but could not find it's config file. Is there something preventing or slowing the reinitialization of sdb during a reboot?

Comment: What are some examples of things that could slow a drive's reinitialization?

Comment: Ignore Boot-Repairs suggestions. I yet to see an UEFI system have issues with the "far from start of disk issue". That was older BIOS systems particularly very old IDE drives and some external drive installs. I have noticed mounting NTFS with fstab slows boot by 10 sec. And if it needs chkdsk then it can take a very long time as it has to time out. But other MSI systems have needed a boot parameter. MSI PX60 2qd 034us Haswell & Optimus libata.force=noncq for SSD hangup
http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=2296878

Comment: Hi oldfred, sorry for the late response. I have tried your suggestions but I'm still getting the same issues. Any other ideas? I feel like the cause of the issue has to do with the drive setup, which is non-stock and has multiple SSDs.